# CSS Display Issue

Tags: html, css

I have been modifying my opencart template and I have come across a strange css issue:

Area's I have modified:

- Header to enable a longer wider header
- Lowered the search box to position inside the navigation
- Created a right-column div for data used on the home template only

I have tried overriding the .tpl files to see if it was something that I had altered in them   ,  I also removed my right-column no change.

I then uploaded the original stylesheet and the issue was fixed minus my header and formatting missing.

I have a feeling it is to do with the way I have coded the header but I cannot spot any bugs.

I have included the original css and view and my css and view:

**Original View:**

[image]

**Original CSS:**

Was over my body limit original [here](https://gist.github.com/1169447)

**My View:**

[image]

**My CSS:**

Was over my body limit My CSS [Here](https://gist.github.com/1169452)

Comment: can you provide a link to some html/css with the new layout ... it would be easier for me to inspect elements on the page with Firebug, then to go through a TON of CSS

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write HTML to match existing CSS. Looking at that CSS I am seeing nightmare selectors such as `#menu > ul > li > div > ul > li > a` My guess is that it'll be easier to scrap the CSS altogether and write your own fro scratch.

Comment: @Martin http://www.thetradinghouse.co.nz/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CSS isn't even displaying for that section, so you probably have an error in your CSS (or HTML, but in this case I feel like CSS is more likely). A really quick, nice check for this is to set the element you are concerned isn't updating to `display: none;` and see if it disappears. If it doesn't, you have a CSS error in a section above that bit of code. Fixing that should fix your problem.

Comment: Your right,  I will start looking at the code before the product css

Comment: Were you able to find the problem?

Comment: sorry for the late reply,  wish we had notifications,  No I have not I have looked and looked over that stylesheet again.

Comment: Fix lines 347-348 (`-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px;` and `-mox-border-radius-bottomleft:5px;` should be `-moz-border-radius-top-left:5px;` and `-mox-border-radius-bottom-left:5px;`)

Comment: That did not work I have looked over the sheet and tried deleting cache clearing etc no luck